# Query MSSQL geography data type against a bounding box

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I'm currently storing geographic locations as data type geography in my MSSQL database and performing radius queries against it without issue.

Is it possible to query against it using a polygon bounding box of points so that the results returned fit within the bounding box?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [EnvelopeAggregate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/envelopeaggregate-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) function. I only tested using geometry data type, but let me know if this works for geography too...

Here is the SQL syntax for selecting a group of points and intersecting them against the bounding box of another set of points:

```
;

WITH cte_pts
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM points_table 
    )
    , cte_box
AS (
    SELECT geometry::EnvelopeAggregate(pb.geom) AS geom
    FROM points_for_box AS pb
    WHERE pb.column = 'value'

    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_pts AS p
JOIN cte_box AS b
    ON p.geom.STIntersects(b.geom) = 1
```

Comment: Should be noted that with Geography there is not a bounding box returned from EnvelopeAggregate, but rather a bounding object made of circular arcs.  Try `SELECT Geography::EnvelopeAggregate(G) FROM (VALUES(Geography::Point(1,1,4326)),(Geography::Point(-1,-1,4326)),(Geography::Point(-2,1.5,4326)))G(G)  UNION ALL SELECT G.STBuffer(10000) FROM (VALUES(Geography::Point(1,1,4326)),(Geography::Point(-1,-1,4326)),(Geography::Point(-2,1.5,4326)))G(G)` and have a look at the spatial pane

Answer (score 0):

```
select geography::STGeomFromText(
 geometry::STGeomFromText(geo.STAsText(),4326).MakeValid().STEnvelope().STAsText(),4326) geo
from ...
```

Comment: An explanation of  how this code answers the question would be appropriate